VBA Userform Add Button will not move
I am working on a UserForm with excel VBA.  As a newbie to this, I am trying to get my "add" button to do the following actions:

Put the user provided information from the text and comboboxes in sepecific columns and cells.
Clear all of the text and comboboxes.
Grab text from three other columns (B,C,and D or 2, 3, 4) in the next row and populate the textboxes in my UserForm.

I need help with this.  Here is the situation.  I am providing the numbers because some think of the numbers more so than column lettering.
The Userform information should be deposited on E2 or cells(2,5) through L2 or cells(2,12) presently my code does not do this.
Then, clear everything out.
Next, the text in row 3 columns B, C, or D should go into  textbox1, textbox2, and textbox3.
This process needs to occur until there isn't anymore valid text in B, C, or D.
My code is putting the entered information in the last row, and then clearing the form, and it is NOT populating the form with the next row of information as I described above.  I have worked on this for 3 days, and I am completely confused. Here is my code:
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim findrow As Range
   Dim cRow As Long
   
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Dim last_row As Long
   last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("D:D"))
   
   sh.Range("E" & last_row + 1).Value = TextBox5.Value
   sh.Range("F" & last_row + 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
   sh.Range("G" & last_row + 1).Value = ComboBox2.Value
   sh.Range("H" & last_row + 1).Value = ComboBox3.Value
   sh.Range("I" & last_row + 1).Value = TextBox4.Value
   sh.Range("J" & last_row + 1).Value = TextBox8.Value
   sh.Range("K" & last_row + 1).Value = TextBox6.Value
   sh.Range("L" & last_row + 1).Value = TextBox7.Value
      
'Clearing all of the values of the boxes
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""

' Set the initial findrow to the first cell in column 2 (e.g., B1)


On Error Resume Next

cRow = Me.Controls.Value
'column D is an id number and is textbox3
Set findrow = Sheet1.Range("D2:D").Find(what:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 0)

If findrow = "" Then Exit Sub

Set findrow = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)

cNum = 3
' Loop to fill Textboxes based on values from columns 2 and 3
For x = 1 To cNum
    ' Assign value from the current findrow to Textbox1 and Textbox2
    Me.Controls("Textbox" & x).Value = findrow.Value  ' Fill Textbox1 with the value from column 2
    Me.Controls("Textbox" & (x + 1)).Value = findrow.Offset(0, 1).Value  ' Fill Textbox2 with the value from column 3
    Me.Controls("Textbox" & (x + 2)).Value = findrow.Offset(0, 1).Value  ' Fill Textbox3 with the value from column 3
    ' Move to the next row
    Set findrow = findrow.Offset(1, 0)
Next x

On Error GoTo 0
   
    
End Sub

Any help will be greatly appreciated, advice, or if someone has asked the same question and I am unaware, please, feel free to point me in the proper direction.

Please comment out On Error Resume Next to check if you get an error.

Set findrow = Sheet1.Range("D2:D").Find(...   that's not a valid range address

I took out the On Error Resume Next.  I did not get an error.

I changed the "D2:D" to "D:D" and still the same problem persists.

What about cRow = Me.Controls.Value ?  Did you name a control Controls ?  That seems like a bad idea since the userform already has a Controls property...

Please run you code step wise an check if you working on the correct cells. By the way, why are you setting findrow always to cells(2,2)?

I see, and I have changed the Me.Controls to represent the textbox that I want.  Still no movement.

I was setting findrow to cells(2,2) to give it a starting point.  I as noted--newbie.

By doing that you're ignoring the result of the Find()

Ok, I see.  Thank you;

This updated VBA code allows users to navigate through rows of data in Excel using a UserForm, load the data into ComboBoxes and TextBoxes, and update the data back into the worksheet. The key enhancement here is the use of a CurrentRow() function to dynamically handle the current row range, and the addition of UpdateCurrentRowIndex() to write form data back to the worksheet.

CommandButton2_Click: When clicked, this button updates the current
row's data from the form and then moves to the next row. If the last
row is exceeded, it resets to the FirstRow and informs the user via a
message box.
UserForm_Initialize: Initializes the form, setting the starting row
to FirstRow and loading data from that row.
CurrentRow (Function): Returns the range (E1 ) of the current row,
simplifying the management of the row data and ensuring that Excel
navigates to the current row.
LoadCurrentRow: Loads data from the current row (columns E to L) into
the form's ComboBoxes and TextBoxes.
UpdateCurrentRowIndex: Updates the current row's data with the values
from the form's ComboBoxes and TextBoxes.
ClearControls: Clears all ComboBoxes and TextBoxes in the form.

This version of the code improves organization by clearly separating concerns (loading data vs. updating data), and the use of the CurrentRow() function streamlines row handling.
Option Explicit
Private CurrentRowIndex As Long
Private Const FirstRow As Long = 3

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    UpdateCurrentRowIndex
    CurrentRowIndex = CurrentRowIndex + 1
    LoadCurrentRow
    
    If CurrentRowIndex > Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("D:D")) Then
        CurrentRowIndex = FirstRow
        LoadCurrentRow
        MsgBox "You have reached the end of the data. The review process is restarting from the beginning.", vbInformation, "Review Restarted"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CurrentRowIndex = FirstRow
    LoadCurrentRow
End Sub

Function CurrentRow() As Range
    Set CurrentRow = Sheet1.Rows(CurrentRowIndex).Range("E1:L1")
    Application.Goto CurrentRow
End Function

Sub LoadCurrentRow()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = CurrentRow
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = Target.Cells(1, 1)
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = Target.Cells(1, 2)
    Me.ComboBox3.Value = Target.Cells(1, 3)
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Target.Cells(1, 4)
    Me.TextBox2.Value = Target.Cells(1, 5)
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Target.Cells(1, 6)
    Me.TextBox4.Value = Target.Cells(1, 7)
    Me.TextBox5.Value = Target.Cells(1, 8)
    Me.TextBox6.Value = Target.Cells(1, 9)
    Me.TextBox7.Value = Target.Cells(1, 10)
    Me.TextBox8.Value = Target.Cells(1, 11)
End Sub

Sub UpdateCurrentRowIndex()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = CurrentRow
    Target.Cells(1, 1) = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 2) = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 3) = Me.ComboBox3.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 4) = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 5) = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 6) = Me.TextBox3.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 7) = Me.TextBox4.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 8) = Me.TextBox5.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 9) = Me.TextBox6.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 10) = Me.TextBox7.Value
    Target.Cells(1, 11) = Me.TextBox8.Value
End Sub

Sub ClearControls()
    'Clearing all of the values of the boxes
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox3.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
End Sub

